# Process from standard input line by line

Tags: c++, testing, vector, input, file-io

Given problem like this:
Find the min and max from a list of integers. There are T test cases, for each test, print no. of current test cases and the answer.

Input.txt file

```
3
3 4 5 1 2
100 22 3 500 60
18 1000 77 10 300
```

Output

```
Test case 1: Max :5, Min :1
Test case 2: Max :500, Min :3
Test case 3: Max :1000, Min :10
```

In C++, how can I process only one line from standard input in each test case iteration. The code that I have tried is like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

int main() {
   
   freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
   int T;
   cin>>T;

   for(int i=1; i<=T; ++i) {
        vector<int> arrayInt;
        int n;

        //Should only process one line for each test case
        while(cin>>n) {
            arrayInt.push_back(n);
        }

        int max = *max_element(arrayInt.begin(), arrayInt.end());
        int min = *min_element(arrayInt.begin(), arrayInt.end());
        cout<<"Test case " << i << ": Max :" << max << ", Min :"<< min << "\n";
   }

}
```

Output that I got when I run it on the command line

```
Test case 1: Max :1000, Min :1
```

Please help me to fix my code. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: do yourself a favour and do not try to learn C++ from coding challenges. They are not meant to teach the language, they assume you already know it. `std::getline` should be covered in any introduction to C++ i/o. If you want to learn C++, better try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: I know, it is just that this might be a general problem that not only appear on coding challenges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++, how can I process only one line from standard input in each test case iteration.

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reads until it finds a line break (thats the default, other delmiters can be used).

Replace

```
    while(cin>>n) {
        arrayInt.push_back(n);
    }
```

With

```
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::istringstream linestream{line};       
    while(linestream >> n) {
        arrayInt.push_back(n);
    }
```

Also note that there is [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) which can get both min and max in a single pass.

Comment: After I changed it I got nothing when I run it on the command line

Comment: @AkhmadZaki It's because it suddenly becomes mixing of formatted input and unformatted input. `cin>>T;` leaves a `\n` (newline) in the stream and that will make the first `getline` read an empty line. You need to add error checking to your program. Anyway, after `cin>>T;` add  `stream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` and the following `getline` will work fine. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/6G7fvzPdj)